# Why won't this code permute the value Z?

Tags: linux, c

So I am trying to build a simple program in C that permutes the value of `z` (`z` is equal to `x + y`) but every single thing I try differently doesn't work. Seriously frustrated here. Please help me understand.

Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int x, y, z;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanf("%d", &y);
    z = x + y;
    printf("%d", &z);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're printing the address of `z`, not the stored value, because you're passing `printf` a pointer to `z` rather than the value. Change the `printf` line to:

```
printf("%d", z);
```

`scanf` already returns a success value so has to use another way to give you the input. The argument you're passing (`&x`) is a pointer to the variable you want to use for storage. That's what the ampersand is for. It says "use the address of this variable".

`printf`, on the other hand, just wants the values themselves. It doesn't need an address. (Though, technically, strings get passed in as pointers. Probably not a distinction you need to worry about right now.)